# @SelectPackages not working with Maven CLI

Tags: junit4, junit5

I run `mvn clean package` and all other tests run except the suite test. I'm running both Junit 4 and 5 tests - @Rules tests run and @RegisterExtension/@ExtendWith tests also run. Not sure why the suite will not run - any ideas?

The code follows:

Test suite

```java
@SelectPackages("com.company.platform.test.suite")
@IncludeClassNamePatterns({"^.*Suite$"})
public class SuiteTest {
}
```

Test being called by `SuiteTest`

```java
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class TestingSuite {
    @Test
    public void add_2_plus_1(){
        Assertions.assertThat(2 + 1).isEqualTo(3);
    }
}
```

Pom

```xml
        <junit-jupiter-engine.version>5.5.0</junit-jupiter-engine.version>
        <junit-platform-runner.version>1.5.0</junit-platform-runner.version>
        <!-- ellided -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform-runner.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      <!-- ellided -->
      <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Maven, Java and OS details

```
mvn11 --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Sun Jul 21 14:43:24 EDT 2019
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T14:33:14-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.4/libexec
Java version: 11.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Users/me/Downloads/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: Your suite class is actually using Junit4 to run Junit5 tests. I guess you need additional dependency to junit 4.12. That said, why don’t you use native support for Junit5 in maven surefire plugin?

Comment: `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` makes it run on Junit4, if I remove it so that it runs native Junit5 - it still does not work. Bare in mind that my regular Junit4 tests work and my Junit5 tests work as well.

Comment: In that case you should provide a runnable but minimal example so that others - eg I - can replicate the problem and hopefully solve it.

Comment: Added the last code segment to make this runnable

Comment: Just noticed that I expressed myself wrongly in the first comment: The suite feature using `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` is JUnit 4 only. It was created to enable JUnit 5 testing w/o JUnit 5 support. There exists nothing like that for JUnit 5. What I meant with native support is just running plain Jupiter test cases out of the box which you already do.

Comment: Yes I added `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` because it was not running "out of the box" - and it didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I replicated your problem. When running

```
mvn clean test
```

i got the following output (among many others):

```
Juli 23, 2019 8:17:30 VORM. org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder$DefensiveAnnotatedBuilder buildRunner
WARNING: Ignoring test class using JUnitPlatform runner: com.example.project.SuiteTest
```

That's why I looked up the code of `DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder$DefensiveAnnotatedBuilder` and found the following comment:

```
/**
 * Customization of {@link AnnotatedBuilder} that ignores classes annotated
 * with {@code @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)} to avoid infinite recursion.
 */
private static class DefensiveAnnotatedBuilder extends AnnotatedBuilder {...}
```

This strongly suggests that suites using `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` are ignored when run through the platform mechanism. You might ask the junit 5 team if there is an explicit way to switch that security mechanism off but I'd guess there is none.

I suggest you extend the configuration of maven-surefire-plugin to mimic what you do in the suite:

```
@SelectPackages("com.company.platform.test.suite")
@IncludeClassNamePatterns({"^.*Suite$"})
```

can be translated into something like

```
<include>com.company.platform.test.suite/*Suite.java</include>
```

I didn't test it though.

Comment: What happens if you run it without `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` - which is what I'm ultimately trying to do?

Comment: Nothing happens. It's the JUnitPlatform runner that picks up the other annotations. Without the runner the class is just being ignored. There is no suite feature in Jupiter.

Comment: But I'm not using `org.junit.runners.Suite`, the class is called Suite but it's just a regular class. Why does Junit5, which runs the other tests that are annotated with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`, not just run. For you nothing happens, for me nothing happens also - so why is that happening just for `@SelectPackages`?

Comment: Not sure if you are trolling me or if I’m really that unclear. Creating test suites with annotations like @SelectPackages etc. is not supported by Jupiter. That has nothing to do with the  class org.junit.runners.Suite.

Comment: Maybe reading this closed Junit5 issue will help to get rid of the confusion: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1778

Comment: That's interesting, I thought `@SelectPackages` was specifically a jupiter/Junit5 construct that replaced `Suite`. The link you said also referenced `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` - I think I added confusion by bringing that into the equation but I think I have enough to go on from ur feedback and the link - thanks.